# Over current detection

Tags: protection, short-circuit

I need a help in designing the circuit to detect if the load current(exceeds 1 Ampere) for 2 ms .This is mainly a test circuit to simulate a squib.

Comment: I thought of using current sense resistor followed by opamp.But my concern is the response time

Comment: Your question is incomplete, consider revising. Tell us about a current sense circuit with a fast response time and tell what you want. We can't help if you give us nothing.

Comment: Do you mean if a current pulse is longer than 2 ms or do you need a response time of less than 2 ms (so you get a trigger signal after the current has risen above 1 A and 2 ms later you get a signal). Do you only need a yes / no signal or do you need an analog representation of the current value?

Comment: I wanted to build a circuit to simulate the function of squib.The squib needs minimum of 1.2A for 2 ms to explode and it should not explode when it receives current of 0.4A under normal condition

Comment: So, you want a circuit that acts like a near-short until it gets >1A for 2ms, then goes open-circuit until reset?

Comment: @Nick Johnson,you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should serve your purposes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0n7Jw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The basic idea is to charge up a capacitor (C1) using the input current until it reaches a certain threshold voltage. The higher the input current, the faster it reaches that threshold, and below a certain critical current, it won't reach it at all. Once the threshold is reached, the device turns off, taking very little current until it's reset. I assume this is in line with how a squib works - more current equals faster ignition.

- V2 is the device (igniter?) you're testing.
- R1 is a shunt that measures the current from the device
- R2, R3 and C1 form a lowpass filter. The voltage at 'sense' charges gradually to half the voltage across R1; how quickly it charges is determined by the values of the three components.
- R6 and R7 form a voltage divider that allow you to set the threshold votlage at which the squib 'goes off'.
- CMP1 compares the voltage across C1 with the voltage from R6. Initially, its output is high, which turns M1 (an N-FET) on, allowing current to flow. When the threshold is reached, the comparator turns M1 off, stopping the current flow.

Hysteresis is provided by the feedback loop through M1, R1, R2 and CMP1: when the FET is shut off, the sense voltage rises to the supply voltage of your test device, keeping the comparator off. Once power is removed, the sense voltage decays until the device resets itself.

Things to watch out for:

- Make sure R1 and M1 can handle the power they're expected to dissipate. Exactly how much power each one has to handle depends on the burden voltage across each (and thus, M1's internal resistance) and the total current through them. Set their combined resistance in line with what you'd expect from a squib.
- Make sure R2 and R3 are much larger than R1, so they don't form a significant current path when the device is triggered, and so they don't unduly affect the trigger point.
- If CMP1 is open-drain, add a pullup to 'sw' - 10k to 100k will do.
- Size C1 and R2/R3 to set how quickly the sense point reaches the desired threshold region.
- Size R7 and R6 so that when R6 is set to one extreme, it just reaches the desired threshold voltage after a significant period, to give a meaningful range of adjustment.
- Make sure CMP1 is rated for at least half the maximum voltage your test device can deliver.

Comment: @thilak My pleasure. You should edit your question to explain in more detail what you were asking for as a favor to people who find this question later, though!

Answer (score 1):

The [LT6118](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6118f.pdf) current sense amplifier has a response time of 500 **ns**.  This shows an example of hooking it up to a µC:

[image]

The resistor divider connected to pin 5, 6 and ground, which sets the trip point, is set for 0.8A in the above diagram, but can easily be changed for 1A; the formula is in the datasheet.

If you need to be able to turn off the supply to the load, you can use a circuit something this:

[image]

You can get the LT6118 [at Digi-Key for $3.37](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LT6118IMS8%23PBF/LT6118IMS8%23PBF-ND/4832976).

Comment: This seems like overkill given the (probable) use-case; an opamp with low side sensing ought to work just fine.